# Can i get link for widget?

Tags: box-api

my site is using box-api to show documents and folders. I created php script what generates new folders structure for projects. Now i want to generate link for every new project folder and embed it as widget to another page of the site. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can generate the link for the embed widget.  Follow the documentation [here](http://developers.box.com/box-embed/)

Note that when you first generate one, you have to send in the right # of 0's into the URL.  Then a random-number will be returned in that spot in the URL.  It isn't generated programatically. It is a random number. It stores the param settings so the next time you load w/ that same random number, it doesn't need to pass all the params to maintain the same look and feel.

Comment: One more question. Creating of widget for the folder is clear, is there any manual for creating widget for file (equivalent for "embed file to site" in interface?